# NSURLsession &JSON causing very long delay in loading table view

Tags: objective-c, json, nsurl

I'm having a problem with my table view taking a very long time to load (sometimes around 20+ seconds). First off this has nothing to do with our server or internet connection, I've checked getting the data via another system and its working well.
Please find below the code from my ViewDidLoad, you'll notice that there is an NSLOG printing out the contents of dataArray. To try and find where the problem is, I set two break points in my table view controller one the line after the NSLOG and the other at the start of the cellForRowAtIndexPath. When I run it, it gets to the first breakpoint and also shows the correct dataArray information almost immediately with no delay ie it has retrieved the JSON data very quickly.
I stop the program and run it again, this time I click continue as soon as it stops at the first breakpoint, it takes 20+ seconds, before the second breakpoint is reached (I'm only loading 3 cells, so find this a little excessive).
I am pretty new to this, so may well be making some newbee error. 
Either way any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks

```
//  Set up the session configuration
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:teacherUrl]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {

                if (!error) {
                    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                    if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200){

                        NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

                        // move serialised JSON into Array (as the data contained is in array)
                        dataArray=(NSArray*)[jsonData copy];
                    NSLog(@"datarr == %@", dataArray);
                        [self.tableView reloadData];



                    }
                }
            }



      ]resume];

    }


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Return the number of rows in the section.


    return [dataArray count];

 }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"teacherCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


// Load and display name
    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    nameLabel.text = [dataArray[indexPath.row] valueForKeyPath: @"firstName"];

// Load and display address
    UILabel *addressLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    NSString *city = [dataArray[indexPath.row] valueForKeyPath: @"address.city"];
    addressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", city];

// Load and display rating star images
    NSNumber *rating = [dataArray[indexPath.row] valueForKeyPath: @"rating"];
    UIImageView *ratingImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    ratingImageView.image = [self imageForRating:rating];

// Load and display subjects
    UILabel *subjectLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
    NSArray *arr = [dataArray [indexPath.row] valueForKeyPath:@"subjects"];
    NSString * subject1String = [arr[0] valueForKeyPath: @"name"];
    NSString * subject2String = @" ";
    NSString * dots = @" ";
    if (arr.count >1) {
        subject2String = [arr[1] valueForKeyPath: @"name"];
        if (arr.count >2) {
            dots = @"...";
        }
    }

   subjectLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", subject1String, subject2String, dots];

// Load and display review
    UILabel *reviewLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:104];
    reviewLabel.text = [dataArray[indexPath.row] valueForKeyPath: @"hotReview"];

// Load and display Number of lessons
//    UILabel *noOfLessonsLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:105];
//    noOfLessonsLabel.text = [dataArray[indexPath.row] valueForKeyPath: @"lessons"];

// Load and display distance
    UILabel *distanceLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:106];
    //distanceLabel.text = [dataArray[indexPath.row] valueForKeyPath: @"firstName"];
    distanceLabel.text = @"1.5km";


// Load and display photo using SDWEBImage
    UIImageView *photoImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:120];

    NSString *urlPhotoId = [dataArray [indexPath.row]valueForKeyPath:@"picture.id"];
    NSString *urlPhoto = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://soon.nextdoorteacher.com/img/profiles/%@.jpg", urlPhotoId];

    [photoImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlPhoto] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mortarboard2"]];

    return cell;
}


- (UIImage *)imageForRating:(NSNumber*)rating
{

    if (rating.floatValue >=1 && rating.floatValue <2) {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"1starimage"];
    }else if (rating.floatValue  >=2 && rating.floatValue <3){
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"2starimage"];
    }else if (rating.floatValue >=3 && rating.floatValue <4){
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"3starimage"];
    }else if (rating.floatValue >=4 && rating.floatValue <5){
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"4starimage"];
    }else if (rating.floatValue >=5){
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"5starimage"];
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: in general you need to do this stuff asynchronously... so if the UI needs to be disabled, you can put up a in determinant progress indicator or similar... then fire this off on a background thread, after you have the data, you update the datasource, then notify the main thread that you are done, and need to update somehow... because you aren't ever in control of how long a network operation will take

Comment: @GradyPlayer NSURLSession is actually highly asynchronous by default, so that's likely not the issue. Try switching to an NSURLConnection instead of an NSURLSession to see if that helps. Something might be getting screwed up with the caching mechanism in NSURLSession. You could also try switching this line:

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

to this: NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];

to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @MySpecialPurpose, you know I didn't really read very carefully UI blocking isn't even going on... why don't you put your comment together as an answer...

Comment: also I guess it should be noted that you could look at your HTTP request and make sure there is a content-length header, it isn't a required header, but without it your client won't know when to hang up... so it would have to wait for the server to close the connection or it would have to time out somehow...

Comment: @MySpecialPurpose I tried changing to ephermeral, but that didn't fix it

Comment: @GradyPlayer I would except I don't think I've figured it out just yet, lol.

Comment: It's actually blocking after the network request is totally done. It's on the main thread after that NSLog so it's waiting on something else to finish. I just don't know what else you're doing that could be blocking this. I don't think it has anything to do with the network connection since that's already completed once you hit that NSLog. Can you post the delegate methods for the UITableView?

Comment: I added the other methods from the table view controller.

Comment: You need to do all UI work on the main thread. Make sure you call `reloadData` on the main thread, not a background thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ahh, @rmaddy is right (as is usual ;) these completion handlers aren't guaranteed to be on the main thread. I usually use the NSURLConnection method sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: which allows you to pass in the mainQueue to guarantee that the completion block will run on the main thread. You might want to switch to that if you don't want to add in GCD. The 'To reload table data on main thread' edit that RahulMishra added should work but as an alternative you could rewrite that method using NSURLConnection like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:teacherUrl];
[NSURLConnection
      sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                        queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
            completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSData *data,
                                NSError *connectionError) {
                if (!connectionError) {
                    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                    if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200){

                        NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

                        // move serialised JSON into Array (as the data contained is in array)
                        dataArray=(NSArray*)[jsonData copy];
                    NSLog(@"datarr == %@", dataArray);
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: You don't want the completion handler here to be on the main queue. No need to do all of the JSON processing on the main queue. Just call `reloadData` on the main queue.

Comment: ok, thats sorted it, works very well now, and I learnt a lot more about this, thanks everyone :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are making synchronous request thats why your UI is blocked.

either You use blocks , [GCD](http://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1) or use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for this. It is simple library for Getting and Posting Data.

Here is the code to make a request:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager =    [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

**To reload table data on main thread**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 [tableView reloadData];
  });
```

Comment: No, the OP is doing the request in the background. The problem is that the OP is reloading the table view from the background. The call to `reloadData` needs to be made on the main thread.

Comment: The new part you just added should be the entire answer (with an explanation). Everything else is wrong.